# create a CNAME record for AWS LoadBalancer DNS name

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, amazon-web-services

I am trying to setup a loadBalancer on AWS.  The A-Record it gave me looks like `myLoadBalancer-**********.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`
however when i try to put that in my domain registrars A-Record, i get an error
`IP address is not valid. Must be of type x.x.x.x where x is 0-255.`
amazons solution is
`you should create a CNAME record for the LoadBalancer DNS name, or use Amazon Route 53
to create a hosted zone.`

**route 53** gives me DNS numbers but if i use that then my email doesnt work from the registrar.
**question**: is there a way to use **route 53** and retain my emails? or should i `create a CNAME record for the LoadBalancer DNS name`, if so how do i do this ... not sure what this means?

Comment: "The A-Record it gave me looks like" -- your confusion starts here.  That's not an "A record".  Nor is it an IP address, which is what goes *into* A records.  Amazon has not, does not, and will not claim that the static identifier for your Elastic Load Balancer is an A record or an IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> question: is there a way to use route 53 and retain my emails?

Yes, you just need to set up MX records that point at your mail server.

Comment: @tq: Of course they can.  You're not looking right.

Comment: this helps http://serverfault.com/questions/348609/how-do-i-set-an-mx-record-in-route53-for-a-godaddy-domain