# Setup and use GoDaddy's email service from AWS Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, email-server, amazon-route53, godaddy

Domain is registered in GoDaddy, nameservers are managed in AWS Route53, I want to use GoDaddy's email service.

Per [the suggestion here](https://serverfault.com/a/479823/590393), In Route53, I added an MX record with these entries:

```
0 smtp.secureserver.net
10 mailstore1.secureserver.net
```

But I'm facing two problems:

- I'm unable to receive emails with error: "550 5.1.1 `<diego@mydomain.co>`Recipient not found."
- The emails I send, are marked as "untrusted"

[image]

Comment: What are the message headers? What is the domain name?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Which headers from which message? Why do you need the domain name?

Comment: How about one of the messages that Gmail couldn't verify? And we prefer real information for a [variety of reasons](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) mostly related to making it much easier to actually find and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the correct record configuration:

- MX: mail.mydomain.co
- A: mail.mydomain.co, **IP** found when following [this guide](https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-my-server-ip-address-12071)
- TXT: v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net -all